# How do I get Flex Builder to use the selected framework?

Tags: apache-flex, caching, flex3, flexbuilder, flash

I'm attempting to create a Flex Project that will cause the Flash Player to cache the Flex framework.  Flex Builder comes with Flex SDK 3.2.0.3958 and setting the Framework Linkage to use Runtime shared Library (RSL) under Project Properties -> Flex Build Path will separate the framework from my main application and I see that my project's bin-debug directory contains framework_3.2.0.3958.swf and *.swz for distribution.

Flex SDK 3.4 fixes a few bugs, so I configured it as another available sdk and set it as the default SDK. When I compile, I expect the bin-debug directory to contain framework_3.4.0.9271.swf and *.swz; however, Flex Builder is still writing framework_3.2.0.3958.swf and *.swz.

How do I configure Flex Builder to package the correct framework files for Flash Player caching?

Comment: Besides using Flex Builder to compile my projects, I also use Ant.  I've learned that the flexTasks.jar cannot currently, properly parse the runtime-shared-library-path structure.  The work-around is to use <load-config filename="custom-flex-config.xml"/>  In that custom-flex-config.xml you can specify <rsl-url>framework_3.4.0.9271.swz</rsl-url>.  So, modifying Flex Builder's default flex-config.xml is one solution, but what a hack.  Surely, I'm overlooking a configuration option in the IDE.  After all, it allowed me to set both the SDK, and configure usage of RSLs.

Answer (score 0):

Is the 3.4 framework listen in the libraries tab for build path in flex builder?  It it still listed as RSL or Merged into Code?  Are these settings global or just for that project?

Have you tried exporting the project as a release build?  That should recompile everything and recreate your RSL's.  Then go back to compiling a debug version until your code is ready?

Answer (score 0):

> Flex SDK 3.4 fixes a few bugs, so I
>   configured it as another available sdk
>   and set it as the default SDK.

Setting it as Default globally might not be enough, you probably need to go into the individual project and point it at the alternate SDK explicitly. In addition, you want to make sure your linkages are set up correctly at the project level.

Delete the contents of your bin-debug after you have done this and then Clean your project. This should rebuild with the proper RSL files.

---

> [image]